# How to set the width of a message sequence chart (msc)

Tags: width, msc

I want to draw a message sequence chart (`msc`) with latex. The problem is now that the message is too long to fit on the arrow, so how can I set the width of a message sequence chart? Below the lines of the `msc`

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{msc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{msc}{Title}
\declinst{alice}{}{Alice}
\declinst{bob}{}{Bob}
\mess{$x, \{|s|\}_{h(k(A,B))}$}{alice}{bob}
\end{msc}

\end{document}
```

It does compile well. Thank you for an answer.

Comment: Your code does not compile (I added `\usepackage{msc}` and a document class).

Comment: Well I just omitted this part. I have that too.

Comment: @Dr3wBr1ck13: It's advised to provide us with enough information to replicate your problem. Otherwise, we're shooting in the dark most of the time.

Comment: Please add a complete code example and not just a part. In addition, the manual (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/msc, `refman.pdf`) lists the **User definable lengths** in chapter 5.

Comment: The code is still not compilable. Please provide a code that one can copy and paste without further modifications. At least I wasn't able to complete the code by myself (I tried, since you a new here).

Comment: Ok I thought it would be enough. Anyways the link from @Dr.ManuelKuehner helped. You can set the width with \setlength{\instdist}{3.0cm}

Comment: Should I provide a short answer so that others can find it?

Comment: That would be great

Comment: Done. Please accept it so that the question gets closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The files related to the `msc` package are located on CTAN: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/msc.
- Among them, there is the **ref­er­ence man­ual** (`refman.pdf)` and the **user manual** (`manual.pdf`).
- The **ref­er­ence man­ual** lists the **User definable lengths** in **chapter 5**.
- The **user manual** list the **Style parameters** in **chapter 7**.
- Here you can find the relevant lengths that you can change using `\setlength` (in your case `\setlength{\instdist}{3.0cm}` as you state in one of your comments).

[image: manual.pdf]

---

Strangely, I (still) *cannot* compile the MWE that you provide.

> ```
> ! Undefined control sequence.
> <recently read> \c@lor@to@ps 
>
> l.10 \declinst{alice}{}{Alice}
>
> The control sequence at the end of the top line
> of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
> misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
> spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
> and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
> ```

[image]

Comment: Oh I see. I think I had to switch to the XeLaTeX engine.